# Getting started with Vue Storefront

Tags: vue.js, e-commerce, vue-storefront

I am trying to build multi vendor eCommerce progressive web application and I came across vue storefront. Although the documentation is very helpful I want to hear if I have made the right choice and where I could find some resources to build. Thanks in adavnce.

Answer (score 0):

We had an e-commerce website built using Magento 2. Recently we decided to build our frontend using Vue Storefront PWA. It is feature rich but we've faced lots of issues regarding customizations. So my suggestion is to you that if your project doesn't need highly customization then go for it.